# After git pull, some files are marked as changed in local which are actually behind server

Tags: git, git-merge-conflict

The problem occurs in different people of this repo, the symptom is when someone `git pull`, there will be a lot of changes in pending changes, which are not really his change. These files actually are changed by others and checked in, but somehow git recognize this unchanged local version is latest. It's quite annoying.

How does this happen?

Comment: You're not _sharing_ a single repo, are you?

Comment: Please post the `git status` that shows what you're describing. What tooling are you using? How are your repos arranged?

Comment: Git doesn't use the term "pending changes" - that's something Visual Studio says, and Visual Studio (even the latest changes to the Git UX in Visual Studio 16.10) is probably the worst git frontend I've ever used... so I suspect you're getting confused or misled by the UX.

Comment: Can you please explain in more details what you mean by : "there will be a lot of changes in pending changes ?" What command/GUI shows you these changes ?

Comment: Also : can you give a more complete list of what you did before reaching this issue ? for example : "Starting from a clean repo (no changes listed), I run `git pull`, the output shows that this command succeeds without error, then I run `git status` and I see that some files are flagged as modified" (together with the output of such commands, if possible)

Comment: yeah maybe pending changes is not correct describe. the scenario is that: after pull, in the visual studio/code UI there suddenly show up lots of file in changes, while running `git status` at that moment, there will be a lot of 'Changes not staged for commit', if the victim trying to undo this changes, they will show up again after another pull. And it's not matter to do pull in GUI and command, they end up with same result, there is no error or warning in command way.

Comment: honestly I don't know what's the complete list of action before this issue, this issue did not happened in my local but my colleagues, that's why i trying to figure out what could be the potential cause and avoid them to mess up again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that because the guy is using squash commit to complete his PR while his PR had some merged changes with other people.

Then next time he try to pull the main branch and merge it into his local change, git bring all the merged changes back again because squash had removed all the commit hash.